# Install latest version of node-soap

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-soap

I am trying to install last version of [node-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).

I execute:

```
npm install soap
```

The installation works ok but install the 0.12 rather than 0.15 which is the latest version according to its `npm` page.

Is there a way to install the latest version?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do the following :

```
 sudo npm install soap@0.15.0
```